# JFrog Artifactory API query for object properties does not return requested detail

Tags: rest, docker, artifactory, attached-properties

I am requesting label properties for docker artifact, perhaps the url is not correct? I get response object (json) but label properties are not included. Code example:

```
  response = Net::HTTP.get_with_headers("http://myrepo:8081/artifactory/api/storage/dockerv2-local/anonymizer/functional/manifest.json;docker.label.com.company.info.build='*'", 
                          {'Authorization' => 'Bearer <REDACTED>'})
  if response.code.to_s == "200"
    puts ("Artifactory response "+ response.body)
    puts ("response object: "+response.inspect())
  else
    puts ("Artifactory request returned "+response.code.to_s)
  end

Connecting to artifactory
Artifactory response {
  "repo" : "dockerv2-local",
  "path" : "/anonymizer/functional/manifest.json",
  "created" : "2018-03-14T14:52:22.681-07:00",
  "createdBy" : "build",
  "lastModified" : "2018-03-15T15:52:34.225-07:00",
  "modifiedBy" : "build",
  "lastUpdated" : "2018-03-15T15:52:34.225-07:00",
  "downloadUri" : "http://myrepo:8081/artifactory/dockerv2-local/anonymizer/functional/manifest.json",
  "mimeType" : "application/json",
  "size" : "1580",
  "checksums" : {
    "sha1" : "bf2a1f85c7ab8cec14b64d172b7fdaf420804fcb",
    "md5" : "9c1bbfc77e2f44d96255f7c1f99d2e8d",
    "sha256" : "53e56b21197c57d8ea9838df7cffb3d8f33cd714998d620efd8a34ba5a7e33c0"
  },
  "originalChecksums" : {
    "sha256" : "53e56b21197c57d8ea9838df7cffb3d8f33cd714998d620efd8a34ba5a7e33c0"
  },
  "uri" : "http://myrepo:8081/artifactory/api/storage/dockerv2-local/anonymizer/functional/manifest.json"
}
response object: #<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to get the properties of the manifest.json file, "docker.label.com.company.info.build" in particular.

From looking at your command:

```
response = Net::HTTP.get_with_headers("http://myrepo:8081/artifactory/api/storage/dockerv2-local/anonymizer/functional/manifest.json;docker.label.com.company.info.build='*'",
```

It seems that you are using a semicolon to get the properties, which is not the right way. As you can see in this REST API, in order to use the get properties you should use the ampersand sign, so your command should look like:

```
response = Net::HTTP.get_with_headers("http://myrepo:8081/artifactory/api/storage/dockerv2-local/anonymizer/functional/manifest.json&docker.label.com.company.info.build='*'",
```

---

Comment: Using ampersand results in 404 response. If I use a question-mark, I do get the json response, but still no properties.

Comment: I also tried this form: .../manifest.json?properties\[=docker.label.com.company.info.build\]" as described in https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ItemProperties

Comment: Someone in my organization suggested using AQL, but that is so much more convoluted, I cannot grok the structure of the request

Comment: This is what I get when doing properties rest api:
curl -iuadmin:password http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/storage/libs-release-local/org/jfrog/test/multi1/3.10/multi1-3.10.jar?properties
{
  "properties" : {
    "TI" : [ "rocks" ],
    "artifactory.licenses" : [ "Apache-2.0" ],
    "build.name" : [ "maven" ],
    "build.number" : [ "104" ],
    "build.timestamp" : [ "1508480554177" ],
    "vcs.revision" : [ "86591d258b67d15ea839c35aa1f7b4cfc355764a" ]
  },
  "uri" : "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/storage/libs-release-local/org/jfrog/test/multi1/3.10/multi1-3.10.jar"